# Function chain isnt working Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Sorry not exactly a function chain but I have this code

```
ActivityService._hubConnection.on('Send', (activity: ActivityDto) => {
   this.activity = activity;
   if (activity.title === 'LOGIN') {
      this.showActivity(`${activity.user.firstName} ${activity.user.surname} logged in.`);
   } else if (activity.title === 'COMMENT') {
      this.showActivity(`${activity.user.firstName} ${activity.user.surname} commented on: XB-ID-${activity.messageId}`, `/app/main/dashboard/xpert-detail/${activity.messageId}/comment`, null);
   } else if (activity.title === 'ASSIGNED') {
      this.showActivity(`${activity.user.firstName} ${activity.user.surname} assigned: XB-ID-${activity.messageId}`, `/app/main/dashboard/xpert-detail/${activity.messageId}/comment`);
   } else if (activity.title === 'SYNC COMPLETE') {
      this.showActivity(`Sync complete, View Changes`, `/app/main/dashboard/alerts/all`, 'complete');
   } else if (activity.title === 'FILE') {
      this.showActivity(`${activity.user.firstName} ${activity.user.surname} filed: XB-ID-${activity.messageId}`, `/app/main/dashboard/xpert-detail/${activity.messageId}/comment`)
   } else if (activity.title === 'XPERT SYNC') {
      this.showActivity(`Sync In Progress.`, `/app/main/dashboard/activity`, 'start' );
   }
});

 showActivity(popText, notifLink = null, sync = null) {
    this.popupText = popText;
    if (notifLink !== null) {
        this.notifLink = notifLink;
    }
    if (sync !== null) {
        if (sync === 'complete') {
            this._activityService.finishSync();
        } else if (sync === 'start') {
            this._activityService.startSync();
        }
    }
    this.showNotif();
}

showNotif() {
    const notif = <HTMLElement>document.querySelector('.notification-tab');
    notif.style.display = 'flex';
    notif.style.bottom = '0';
    setTimeout(() => {
        notif.style.bottom = '-50px';
        setTimeout(() => {
            notif.style.display = 'none';
        }, 500);
    }, 5000);
}
```

now I cant figure out why this isnt working, basically what is happening is say im recieving a comment, so the activity.title === 'COMMENT', it should run the `showActivity()` function, which then should run the `showNotif()` function, ive put breakpoints on every part of the functions and the breakpoint hits the this.showActivity() but then nothing happens? none of the other breakpoints are hit and I cannot figure out what the problem is! It doesnt make any sense to me.

Any help would be appreciated, I have no idea what could be going wrong...

Thanks

Comment: What's the value of activity when it stops in your breakpoint at the send callbak?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to wrap you functions to try.. catch, maybe there is uncatch exception.

```
  showActivity(popText, notifLink = null, sync = null) {
   try  {
    this.popupText = popText;
    if (notifLink !== null) {
      this.notifLink = notifLink;
    }
    if (sync !== null) {
      if (sync === 'complete') {
        this._activityService.finishSync();
      } else if (sync === 'start') {
        this._activityService.startSync();
      }
    }
    this.showNotif();
   } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
   }
}
```

And wrap here too)

```
if (activity.title === 'COMMENT') {
  try {
    this.showActivity(`${activity.user.firstName} ${activity.user.surname} commented on: XB-ID-${activity.messageId}`, `/app/main/dashboard/xpert-detail/${activity.messageId}/comment`, null);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
}
```

Comment: Genius, thank you this didnt fix my problem but showed me what the problem was thanks again